# Reading variable values from java class file or from yml and use it in script function

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, yaml, dropwizard

I am working on dropwizard java project.Is there anyway to read the values from yamlBeans or from java class files and use it in script function.

I need to use dynamic values in script for displaying list elements.If anyone knows,please help me to solve.

Comment: Dropwizard already parses a yaml file in its configuration. Why not add your values there?